# In R grid package , how to use viewport for merge ggplot2 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I want to merge geom_point() and geom_boxplot() into one plot as attached image.Below code can't work.Anyone can help on this? Thanks!

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width = 1,height = 1)
push.Viewport(vp)
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))

vp_sub <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.7,width=0.3,height=0.3)
push.viewport(vp_sub)
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `viewport` you could accomplish your task this way. If you want to save in a png then just comment out the line `#png("my_plot.png")`

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
grid.newpage()

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))


vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width = 1,height = 1)vp_sub <- viewport(x=0.73,y=0.8,width=0.4,height=0.3)

#png("my_plot.png")
print(p1, vp=vp)
print(p2, vp=vp_sub)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the `patchwork` package, there's a [section](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html) that describes your problem exactly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

p1 + inset_element(
  p2, 
  left = 0.5, 
  bottom = 0.5, 
  right = unit(1, 'npc') - unit(1, 'cm'), 
  top = unit(1, 'npc') - unit(1, 'cm')
)
```

[image: patchwork_insert_element]

Answer (score 4):

Besides `patchwork::inset_element` a second option would be to add your boxplot via `ggplot2::annotation_custom`. However, in contrast to `patchwork::inset_element` you have to set the positions in absolute coordinates of the data range of your main plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

bp <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

base <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) 

base +
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(bp), xmin = 22.5, ymin = 250)
```

[image]